# How would I put a dict {key: value} in it's designated key in a dictionary so that it is {key: {key: value}} after counting value

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dictionary

I have a csv file where I am trying to count `row[3]` then connect it with `row[0]`

```
 row[0]      row[3]
 'A01'          'a'
 'B02'          'a'
 'A01'          'b'
 'A01'          'a'
 'B02'          'a'
 'A01'          'a'
```

so that in the end it should be

```
 {'A01':{a:3, b:1, 'B02':{a,2}}
```

I have this code so far:

```
d = {'job': {'general_types': 0}}
d['job'] ={}
d['general_types'] ={}
with open("sample.csv", "r") as data1:
    outcome_reader = csv.reader(data1)
    for rows in outcome_reader:
        d['job'].setdefault(rows[0])
        d['general_type'].setdefault(rows[3],0)
        d['general_type'][rows[3]] += 1
```

Currently however I'm getting a `KeyError: 'general_type'`

Comment: you are missing a closing brace in your second code sample that makes it really hard to understand what you're looking for there. But your KeyError is because you've defined a key `general_types` and are attempting to access the singular `general_type`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `KeyError` is raised whenever you're requesting a key from a dictionary that does not exist.

It looks like you're declaring the key as `'general_types'` and then are requesting it by the name `'general_type'`. Try this instead:

```
d['general_types'].setdefault(rows[3],0)
d['general_types'][rows[3]] += 1
```